# AMD Microphone not detected on Debian

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, drivers, audio, amd

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 14ARE05 and have installed Debian SID on it. The internal mic isn't detected in pulvac. After a lot of googling, I figured out that my issue is very similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258015/1116492). However, when that solution was posted, kernel 5.8 was just released. Now Debian has 5.10 by default. Still, the required driver `snd_rn_pci_acp3x`, is still not visible in `modprobe`. Is there a way to install it?

Edit: The mic is working in Ubuntu Live USB

Edit: These might help

```
# cat /etc/modprobe.d/local-blacklist.conf
blacklist snd_hda_intel
blacklist snd_pci_acp3x

# lsmod|grep snd
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_seq                86016  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              49152  2 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer
snd                   110592  5 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_timer
soundcore              16384  1 snd
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       20480  0

# inxi -Fxxxz
...
Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A bus ID: 04:00.1 chip ID: 1002:1637 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A 
           bus ID: 04:00.5 chip ID: 1022:15e2 
           Device-3: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A bus ID: 04:00.6 
           chip ID: 1022:15e3 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.10.0-1-amd64 
...

#lspci -s 04: -nnvvv
04:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [17aa:3822]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 73
    IOMMU group: 5
    Region 0: Memory at c0580000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [64] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 16GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 16GT/s (ok), Width x16 (ok)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR-
             10BitTagComp+ 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt+ EETLPPrefix+, MaxEETLPPrefixes 1
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- OBFF Disabled,
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
             Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee00000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x
```

Comment: what's `pulvac`?

Comment: Pulse Volume Control GUI

Answer (score 1):

You microphone should work on debian Buster with the `linux-image-5.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64-unsigned` linux image installed from `buster-backports`.

On debian Sid you should have `linux-image-5.10.0-1-amd64` or `linux-image-5.10.0-1-amd64-unsigned` installed

to load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -v snd-rn-pci-acp3x
```

Comment: I was already on amd64 image, not the unsigned one. But the modprobe command still didn't help. Also, I've updated the question, please check